# Who is the highest-grossing debut director?

Tags: directors, box-office

I know it's quite difficult to find the answer to this question, I searched all over the internet none matches my question.

Who is the highest-grossing debut director?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Note**: *All information on box office come from [BoxOfficeMojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/world/), and was gathered by simply working my way down the list of highest grossing films of all time and checking who directed them, and if they'd previously directed anything else.*

Using those figures, the highest grossing film from a first-time director would be 2013's *Frozen*, which was directed by first-time director Jennifer Lee alongside Chris Buck, who had directed both *Tarzan* and *Surf's Up* before he worked on *Frozen*. *Frozen* is the seventh highest grossing film ever made, earning $1.276 billion worldwide.

If you are looking for films where all the directors were first time directors, however, then the answer comes from this year's *Deadpool*, which was directed by first-time director Tim Miller and is the 64th highest grossing movie of all time, earning $760.3 million worldwide.

Answer (score 18):

As per [source](http://www.hollywood.com/movies/best-debut-films-57160296) for best directional debut, it is [Tim Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Miller_(director)) who directed [Deadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)) that grossed over $782.6 million.

> Timothy "Tim" Miller is an American film director and visual effects artist. He made his feature film directing debut with Deadpool (2016).

Thanks to @nwellnhof. According to [calculatorgames.info](http://calculatorgames.info/mogul/), the worldwide gross of Grease is $1,203,866,872 when adjusted for inflation. This source puts Grease slightly above Frozen and seems to be accurate and up-to-date.

As per this [article](http://www.indiewire.com/2011/08/the-top-grossing-directorial-debuts-of-all-time-52927/), it is Randal Kleiser, but this article is 5 years old one.

> The directorial debut of Randal Kleiser (who knew?) – remains the top grossing directorial debut of all time, whether one adjusts for inflation or not. Kleiser – who had previously directed TV Movies “The Boy in the Plastic Bubble” (1976), ‘The Gathering” (1977) and “Dawn: Portrait of a Teenage Runaway” (1976) – went on to direct numerous other feature films after “Grease,” including “The Blue Lagoon,” “Honey, I Blew Up the Kid” and “It’s My Party.”

Here is the list.

> Here’s the overall top ten; figures are for North America only and not adjusted for inflation. Animated films were not included due to their tendency to have multiple directors and the fact that they would have dominated the list.
>
> 1. Grease (Randal Kleiser, 1978) – $188,389,888
> 2. Dances With Wolves (Kevin Costner, 1990) – $184,208,848
> 3. Crocodile Dundee (Peter Faiman, 1986) – $174,803,506
> 4. TRON: Legacy (Joseph Kosinski, 2010) – $172,062,763
> 5. Chicago (Rob Marshall, 2002) – $170,687,518
> 6. Sex and the City (Michael Patrick King, 2008) – $152,647,258
> 7. The Santa Clause (John Pasquin, 1994) – $144,833,357
> 8. Mamma Mia! (Phyllida Lloyd, 2008) – $144,130,063
> 9. The Blair Witch Project (Daniel Myrick and Eduardo Sánchez, 1999) – $140,539,099
> 10. The Santa Clause 2 (Michael Lembeck, 2002) – $139,236,327

Comment: Note that according to *calculatorgames.info*, the worldwide gross of Grease is [$1,203,866,872](http://calculatorgames.info/mogul/) when adjusted for inflation. This source puts Grease slightly above Frozen and seems to be accurate and up-to-date.

Comment: wow, 2 of top 10 were from The Santa Clause franchise???

Comment: @nwellnhof $1,203,866,872 for *Grease* when adjusted for inflation still isn't as high as the $1,276,480,335 that *Frozen* earned.